# Particle hair behaving strangely and falling through skull mesh. General mayhem

Tags: particles, hair, particle-edit-mode

I'm new to blender. Really, the only thing I'm using it for is hair creation, so I can import the hair into Unreal Engine for animations.

I figured I'd start with a super simple slicked back hair groom, but I'm running into all sorts of problems. First, after I groomed the particles how I thought they should be, I switched from eevee to cycles to view it and I got this. The top turned out good and the back turned out (relatively) fine, but the sides should *not* be that thin.
[image]

This is what it looks like in particle edit mode. Here, the sides don't look particularly thin. The sides also look uniform in thickness, unlike in the rendered image.
[image]

As an experiment, in particle edit mode, I added about 500 new particle hairs to this left side of the head. When I combed them down however, they made almost no difference. They did fill in a little strip near the forehead and sideburn areas but seemed to do nothing nearer the temple where the hair is particularly thin. Possibly, when I add particles in particle edit mode, they don't have any children??? If that is the case, that would partly explain why they had so little affect, but not why they only seemed to improve one area--I combed them over the whole left side of the head!

Here is another issue that may be related. This image is back in eevee from *inside* the character's head. Obviously the hair should not be falling through his skull, lol.
[image]

I think this may be the reason no hair is showing up in the sideburn area on the right side of his face. I am pretty sure it is all falling through to the inside of his skull. Image one is the right side of his skull showing the weight painting of the vertex group. You can actually see little stubble in the mostly empty area. I think those are hair roots, but none of the rest of the hair is showing. The second image is that same section of the head, but from the inside. There you can see plenty of hair.

[image][image]

Finally, this isn't exactly related, but I saw a tutorial where a guy was combing the hair, and you could actually see all the children as he was combing it. I though that would be extremely useful, but I can't figure out how he activated that setting.